# terminal title not setting within screen

Tags: bash, terminal, gnu-screen

Currently, I'm setting terminal title within `screen` command, but the bash script gives me:

> Cannot exec 'source /etc/profile && title.set root@test': No such file or directory

And I can run above command successful directly from the command line, here are my scripts:

/usr/local/bin/s

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $1 ]
then
    screen -D -R $1 -m "source /etc/profile && title.set `whoami`@$1"
else
    screen -R
fi
```

/etc/profile

```
...
# Source global bash config
if test "$PS1" && test "$BASH" && test -z ${POSIXLY_CORRECT+x} && test -r /etc/bash.bashrc; then
        . /etc/bash.bashrc
fi

function title.set() {
      if [[ -z "$ORIG"  ]]; then
          ORIG=$PS1
      fi
      TITLE="\[\e]2;$*\a\]"
      PS1=${ORIG}${TITLE}

}
# Termcap is outdated, old, and crusty, kill it.
unset TERMCAP

# Man is much better than us at figuring this out
unset MANPATH
...
```

So What's going wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

The keyword `source` is a bash *built-in* command, i.e., something for which there is not necessarily an actual file to *exec* (another built-in command).  You can only **`exec`** something that is a file — like **`bash`**, e.g., something like this:

```
screen -D -R $1 -m bash -c "source /etc/profile && title.set `whoami`@$1"
```